# Why do hotels still put soap bars in the rooms instead of liquid soap?

Tags: hotels

Why do hotels still put soap bars in the rooms? They are so cumbersome to use. They are tiny and slippery, possibly bad for the environment as most will be wasted. Even worse, rarely there is a soap holder in the hotel bathrooms. Soap bars can easily make a mess when they slip. So you go to like even a luxury hotel and you cannot wash your hands hassle-free.

Why don't they provide liquid soap instead of soap bars?

Comment: Is this just a rant? They provide small courtesy bars of soap that are useful for guests, and are almost worthless if stolen. However most restaurant etc toilet rooms do provide liquid handwash.

Comment: @WeatherVane "courtesy"? they are supposed to provide basic personal hygiene products.  And the quiesiton is not a rant. Is your comment a rant?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand "you go to like even a luxury hotel and you cannot wash your hands hassle-free". There is soap and towel, the rest seems like you are trying to make difficulties where none exist. Liquid handwash is quite slippery too. It's just as easy to squirt it somewhere else as it is to drop the soap bar.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. We stayed recently in a nice hotel in Philadelphia that prortrays itself as green and environmentally friendly. They don't have little soap bars, little plastic bottles of shampoos, conditioners, and lotions - rather, everything liquid is in refillable dispensers on bathroom wall. We found it actually more convenient. Also no plastic cups for the coffee. Lots of USB-A charging ports.

Comment: I think you should complain to the hotel. How should we know?

Comment: What did the hotel say when you asked them? https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Frame challenge: many hotels _do_ provide liquid soap.

Comment: @HandsomeNerd I doubt that all of the downvoters were compelled to their action by WeatherVane's comments.  I am skeptical that any of them were.

Comment: @HandsomeNerd, remember the first rule of the site, be nice. Calling the normal for the site comments from a more experienced user nagging is not acceptable. This question does not really fit Travel Stack Exchange.

Comment: @HandsomeNerd, editing in an answer of the length you did is not the way to go. Questions are questions, there is an answer given that holds most of the information you edited in.

Comment: @willeke you were not allowed to undo my edit. I asked a question and I decide if an answer addressed my question not you. Revert the question or delete it. I have been on SE for more than a decade and haven't seen chaos like this ever.

Comment: Feel free to contact staff if you are not happy with how a moderator handles your question on this site. Untill then it is not you who tells the rules.

Answer (score 4):

Plenty of hotels do put liquid soap in the rooms, and some also have dispensers for shower gel and shampoo instead of the little bottles. For those who still use small bars, I can imagine a number of reasons:

- putting a bar or two of soap on the counter is much easier than opening a bottle of liquid soap, filling it without spilling any or overflowing it, and securely reclosing it
- some customers might worry about the soap that had been in the room with another guest and feel it was not as clean as unwrapping a brand new bar of soap
- some customers might not like using a half full container, wanting a fresh full one every time, meaning the staff would have to refill after every customer
- it's possible to spill quite a lot of liquid soap or shampoo if there is some kind of mishap, and someone could slip and fall, and while the odds are very small the liability costs could be enormous, making some companies nervous to take the risk
- installing dispensers on the walls will need a carpenter and perhaps a tiler and be expensive

Personally I don't think hotels are "supposed" to provide me with hygiene items. In many countries, they don't provide soap. I have a small bar of soap (in a smell I like) that I carry with me. (You could also take the remainder of a provided bar that you used only a little of and use it next time.) This allows me to ignore whatever they have provided, sparing the environment completely, and just using a little of what I have brought.

Comment: A few weeks ago I stayed in a nice European hotel. They had squirt bottles for hand soap and body wash nicely mounted on the wall. Except they were both mounted by the wash basin, well out of reach from the shower, which had nothing mounted in it. Fortunately I could with care slip the body wash out of the holder and take it into the shower… A bar of soap would have been easier for sure.